# Was the infanticide of the Hebrews real?

Tags: acts

Acts 7:17-21:

“But as the time drew near for God to fulfill the promise he had declared to Abraham,[as] the people increased greatly in number[at] in Egypt, until another king who did not know about[au] Joseph ruled[av] over Egypt.[aw] This was the one who exploited[ax] our people[ay] and was cruel to our ancestors,[az] forcing them to **abandon**[ba] their infants so they would die.[bb]  At that time Moses was born, and he was beautiful[bc] to God. For[bd] three months he was brought up in his father’s house, and when he had been **abandoned**,[be] Pharaoh’s daughter adopted[bf] him and brought him up[bg] as her own son.

The New English Translation (NET Bible)

Acts 7:17 tn Grk “But as the time for the fulfillment of the promise drew near that God had declared to Abraham.” The order of the clauses has been rearranged to improve English style. See vv. 6-7 above.

Acts 7:17 tn Grk “the people increased and multiplied.”

Acts 7:18 tn Or simply “did not know.” However, in this context the point is that the new king knew nothing about Joseph, not whether he had known him personally (which is the way “did not know Joseph” could be understood).

Acts 7:18 tn Grk “arose,” but in this context it clearly refers to a king assuming power.

Acts 7:18 sn A quotation from Exod 1:8.

Acts 7:19 tn According to L&N 88.147 it is also possible to translate κατασοφισάμενος (katasophisamenos) as “took advantage by clever words” or “persuaded by sweet talk.”

Acts 7:19 tn Or “race.”

Acts 7:19 tn Or “forefathers”; Grk “fathers.”

Acts 7:19 tn Or “expose” (BDAG 303 s.v. ἔκθετος).

Acts 7:19 tn Grk “so that they could not be kept alive,” but in this context the phrase may be translated either “so that they would not continue to live,” or “so that they would die” (L&N 23.89).

Acts 7:20 tn Or “was well-formed before God,” or “was well-pleasing to God” (BDAG 145 s.v. ἀστεῖος suggests the meaning is more like “well-bred” as far as God was concerned; see Exod 2:2).

Acts 7:20 tn Grk “who was brought up for three months.” The continuation of the sentence as a relative clause is awkward in English, so a new sentence was started in the translation by changing the relative pronoun to a regular pronoun (“he”).

Acts 7:21 tn Or “exposed” (see v. 19).

Acts 7:21 tn Grk “Pharaoh’s daughter took him up for herself.” According to BDAG 64 s.v. ἀναιρέω, “The pap. exx. involve exposed children taken up and reared as slaves…The rendering ‘adopt’ lacks philological precision and can be used only in a loose sense (as NRSV), esp. when Gr-Rom. terminology relating to adoption procedures is taken into account.” In this instance both the immediate context and the OT account (Exod 2:3-10) do support the normal sense of the English word “adopt,” although it should not be understood to refer to a technical, legal event.

Acts 7:21 tn Or “and reared him” (BDAG 74 s.v. ἀνατρέφω b).

Answer (score 1):

In his speech to the Sanhedrin (Acts 7), Stephen refers (V19) to the edict of the Pharaoh of the Exodus who decreed that male Hebrew children should be killed at birth.

> The same dealt subtly with our kindred, and evil entreated our
> fathers, so that they cast out their young children, to the end they
> might not live.

However, this is the decree of Pharaoh that was effectively neutralized by the Hebrew midwives at the time as recorded in Ex 1:15-17:

> Then the king of Egypt said to the Hebrew midwives, whose names were
> Shiphrah and Puah, “When you help the Hebrew women give birth, observe
> them on the birthstools. If the child is a son, kill him; but if it is
> a daughter, let her live.”
>
> The midwives, however, feared God and did not do as the king of Egypt
> had instructed; they let the boys live.

The infamous decree of Pharaoh is one of the earliest attempts as mass infanticide that failed because the Hebrews continued to increase in number.

Lastly, the Greek words translated "abandoned" in the OP are in fact, different words:

- Acts 7:19 ἔκθετος (ekthetos) = (adj) cast out, exposed (Thayer)
- Acts 7:21 ἐκτίθημι (ektithemi) = (verb) to place or set out, expose (Thayer) especially of a child when used literally.  The meaning here is an allusion to when Moses was "set outside" in the little boat on the Nile to be (deliberately) discovered by Pharaoh's daughter.

While the two words are clearly related, Stephen is possibly making the point that Moses' mother was complying with the edict and using this exposure to save her son.